# Can I rely on arguments being evaluated before being passed in python?

Tags: python, mocking, peewee

I'm writing a rudimentary mocking framework just so I can test some calls to peewee.

I know in peewee, you can make `where()` calls like
`model.select().where(model.id == target_id). ...`

In order to detect which fields of the model are being compared, I will be overriding the comparison operators of the field.  Then I would inject that model in place of a peewee model.  It would provide the same interface as the peewee model(only as much as needed, though) but instead of accessing a database, it would record comparisons and calls; but it would all depend on the arguments being evaluated *before* the method is called.

I've run an example using anaconda, and for whatever python comes with Linux Mint, and they seem to operate as I would like.  I'm not sure if it's a fluke of runtime, or maybe python really does evaluate comparisons just before they are needed.

So, regarding the following, can I rely on `model.id == target_id, ...` running the comparison before the first `where()` is called?  Can I rely on `model.name == target_name` running its comparison before the second `where()` is called and after the first `where()`?

```
mockModel.select()
         .where(model.id == target_id, model.number == target_number)
         .where(model.name == target_name)
         ...
```

Comment: Expressions in parameters are fully executed into a result object and that object is passed to the function. so, yes,they have to be fully resolved before the call.

Comment: Ok, cool; but how early is that resolve?  Before the containing line?  Before the first call in a method chain?  Are all the expressions evaluated in method chain before any of the methods are called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method parameters are resolved as they are being marshalled for the call. Since the second `where` hasn't been looked up when the first `where` is called, its parameters have not yet been resolved. The sequence for this statement

```
mockModel.select()\
         .where(model.id == target_id, model.number == target_number)\
         .where(model.name == target_name)
```

is

- lookup `mockModel`
- lookup `select` on that object
- it has no parameters, so call it and get its result object
- lookup `where` on the result object
- its a function so evaluate its parameters left to right
- call the function and get its result object
- lookup `where` on the result object
- its a function call, so evaluate its parameters left to right
- call the function

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> The primary must evaluate to a callable object (user-defined functions, built-in functions, methods of built-in objects, class objects, methods of class instances, and all objects having a `__call__()` method are callable). **All argument expressions are evaluated before the call is attempted.**

Comment: So, to be certain, and in terms of the example, `model.name == target_name` will run `__eq__(self, other)`, _after_ the first `where()`, but _before_ the second `where()`?